# Changing C# script to generate a map from a png file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, png, unityscript

In Unity3d I downloaded an asset called Cubiquity, there's an example script that scans a png file of a black and white maze and builds a 3d maze from it.  What I was wondering is how to change the script to look for colors not just black and white?  Or is There is an alternate to this method that might be easier?

Here is the example script

http://pastebin.com/mJucT07c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is just sampling the red of the colour that GetPixels (line 67 in linked script):

```
bool isWall = mazeImage.GetPixel(x, z).r < 0.5; // A black pixel represents a wall
```

So if you want it to test for colours, you would change this to something such as:

```
Color color = mazeImage.GetPixel(x, z);
```

And then from this you could run your if statements or whatever you want to do.

```
if(color.r > 0)
    Debug.Log("Colour is red");
if(color.g > 0)
    Debug.Log("Colour is green");
if(color.b > 0)
    Debug.Log("Colour is blue");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new to c# and thanks for helping understand the code

Comment: is there a way to do an "if" statement looking for RGB and not just one at a time
for example even know its not right
if(color.r = 1 & color.g = 2 & color.b = 3)

Comment: Sure, if(color.r == 1 && color.g == 1 && color.b == 1) Debug.log("The colour white"); Also note that RGBA will always return a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is it possible to change this from color.r color.g color.b to color32 is some way so I can get 256 values?

Comment: @NathanRadtke I'm not certain what your question is, but color.r is clamped between 0 and 1, so if color.r == 0.5 then 0.5 * 255 = 127.5. Color values are normally from 0-255 not 256.